# Where can I find a "ESC/POS" Epson Barcode Test Program?

Tags: delphi, barcode, point-of-sale, opos, epson

I am struggling to get an Epson "ESC/POS" printer to print barcodes (Using Delphi) and want to test if the printer is not faulty. Do you know where I can find a program to print a barcode in "ESC/POS"? I suppose as a last resort an OPOS program will also be OK.

Also, a demo Delphi Program that works will also be fine. All the Delphi snippets I have so far is not working.

The printer I am using is an Epson TM-L60II

Comment: I already have the reference - it doesn't work on my printer thats why I want an already working test program.

Comment: Yep my printer is serial - can u help?

Comment: Give this program a try, I wrote it a while ago but it should still work. http://support.relogic.co.uk/sk/TillTest.zip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I Have a full tests program written in Delphi 5 for the TMT88's but the source is abit big for here so here is the barcode bits

Please note that as its snippets from the full object some vars/functions may be missing

To get the barcode chars

```
{**
*    @param a ean13 barcode numeric value
*    @return the escpos code for the barcode print
*    Description uses escpos code, return code needed to print a ean13 barcode
*}
function TPrintEscPosToPort.getBarcodeEscPosCode(l_ean13:String):String;
    var
        l_return:String;
begin
    l_return :=  CHR(29) + 'k' + CHR(67) + CHR(12);
    l_return := l_return +  l_ean13; // Print bar code
    l_return := l_return +  l_ean13; // Print bar code number under thge barcode

    Result :=  l_return
end;
```

to print to a printer

```
{**
*    @param Printer Name, Item be printed, Cut the papers after the cut, #no of copies to print
*    @return boolen, true if it printed
*    Description prints a test page to the tysso printer
*}
function TPrintEscPosToPort.escPosPrint(const l_printer, l_textToPrint :String;l_cutPaper:Boolean=true;l_copies:integer=1): Boolean;
    var
        l_pPort,l_pName,l_tmp:String;
        i,x:integer;
        PrinterFile: TextFile;
begin
    // set result to false so any thing other then a good print will be false
    Result:= FALSE;

    try
        //Find if the printer exists, else set to defult -1
        i := Printer.Printers.IndexOf(l_printer);
        if (i > -1) then
        begin
            Printer.PrinterIndex := i;
            l_pName := Printer.Printers[i]; //Get the printer name (incase its the defult and not the one passed)
            l_pPort :=   Self.getPrinterPort(l_pName) ; // get the port name from the reg
        end;

        // If true add headers and footers to the passed text
        if (Self.aPrintHeadersFooters) then
        begin
            l_tmp := Self.getHeader()
                 +  l_textToPrint + Self.GetFooter();
        end
        else
        begin
            l_tmp := l_textToPrint;
        end;

      //Send the Document To the printer
      try
          for x:= 1 to l_copies do //Print multi-copies
          Begin              
              //Assign the file to a tmp file in the printer port
              if (length(trim(l_pPort)) > 0) then AssignFile(PrinterFile,l_pPort)
              else
              begin                         
                   //only use if we cant get the port 
                   //(may look bad as ctrl codes are still in place)
                   AssignPrn(PrinterFile);
                   l_tmp := Self.stripEscPos(l_tmp);
              end;

              Rewrite(PrinterFile);

              try
                  //Send the passed Text to the printer 
                  WriteLn(PrinterFile,l_tmp);

                  if (Self.aPrinterReset) then 
                       WriteLn(PrinterFile,escReset);  // Reset the printer alignment

                  if (l_cutPaper) then         
                       WriteLn(PrinterFile,escFeedAndCut); //Cut the paper if needed
              finally
                  CloseFile(PrinterFile);
                  Result:= true;
              end;
          end;
      except
      end;
    except
    end;

end;
```

**Update**

Here is a lost of control code constants from the code above, hopefully the names are descriptive enough.

```
const
     escNewLine   = chr(10);  // New line (LF line feed)
     escUnerlineOn   = chr(27) + chr(45) + chr(1);  // Unerline On
     escUnerlineOnx2 = chr(27) + chr(45) + chr(2);  // Unerline On x 2
     escUnerlineOff  = chr(27) + chr(45) + chr(0);  // Unerline Off
     escBoldOn       = chr(27) + chr(69) + chr(1);  // Bold On
     escBoldOff      = chr(27) + chr(69) + chr(0);  // Bold Off
     escNegativeOn   = chr(29) + chr(66) + chr(1);  // White On Black On'
     escNegativeOff  = chr(29) + chr(66) + chr(0);  // White On Black Off
     esc8CpiOn       = chr(29) + chr(33) + chr(16); // Font Size x2 On
     esc8CpiOff      = chr(29) + chr(33) + chr(0);  // Font Size x2 Off
     esc16Cpi        = chr(27) + chr(77) + chr(48); // Font A  -  Normal Font
     esc20Cpi        = chr(27) + chr(77) + chr(49); // Font B - Small Font
     escReset        = chr(27) + chr(64); //chr(27) + chr(77) + chr(48); // Reset Printer
     escFeedAndCut   = chr(29) + chr(86) + chr(65); // Partial Cut and feed

     escAlignLeft    = chr(27) + chr(97) + chr(48); // Align Text to the Left
     escAlignCenter  = chr(27) + chr(97) + chr(49); // Align Text to the Center
     escAlignRight   = chr(27) + chr(97) + chr(50); // Align Text to the Right
```

Comment: I got it to work, thanks - the key is that (I think) the chr(12) in your barcode routine is setting the length of the barcode to be printed (ie, 12 chars). I'll tidy-up and add my routine to this question asap.

Answer (score 1):

Get the Microsoft POS For .Net 1.11, it's got an SDK that includes a sample application that performs all the basic operations on POS hardware. I'm using it all the time to test that cash drawers work ok for example.

There's also a source code included (in .Net), so you can see how they do it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but I am really looking for a wee-bit easier way than doing all that - just a simple barcode app. already proven to work with.

Comment: First of all, OP is asking for a delphi application not a .NET, also would you care to specify name of sample code mentioned in your answer?